# Add a note below Jqueryui datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to display a note below the calendar when jqueryui datepicker is called.  It should be a div the width of the two months shown.  Appear and hide along with the datepicker.  Any help appreciated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) { 
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<div>No reservation fees!<div>');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ beforeShow: function () {
    setTimeout(appendsomething, 10);
},
onChangeMonthYear: function () {
    setTimeout(appendsomething, 10);
    }
}
);

var appendsomething = function () {
$("#ui-datepicker-div").append("<div class='something'>something</div>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shahar.  Exactly what I needed and works perfectly.  Much appreciated.  Best, Mike

Comment: i am very happy that i can help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without your full widget creation code and some HTML snippets, it's hard to know for sure what the problem is.  Here are some speculative answers:

1. Perhaps the `#ui-datepicker-div` selector is not matching your intended element where you want to append the div.  If you post your HTML, we'll be able to tell for sure.
2. Your HTML in the call to `append` is malformed.  It's not clear if that is *the* cause of your problems, but it should look like this: `.append('<div>No reservation fees!</div>')`.
3. Perhaps you're not instantiating your widget correctly.  Your snippet looks ok, but we cannot see the context where it is placed.  It should look something like this:

JavaScript:

```
$('#dp-element').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('#notes').append('<div>No reservation fees!</div>');
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<input id="dp-element" />
<div id="notes"></div>
```